# Input file doesn't inherit the main language settings

Tags: fontspec, input

I want to create a multi language document using the `fontspec` package and building the document with **XeLaTeX**. Even though multi language characters work fine in the main .tex file, if they be inserted via an `\input` method, they are unrecognizable.  Here's the main file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=1.75cm, bottom=1.75cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}%
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%

\usepackage{fontspec}
\fontspec{Arial}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Arial}


\begin{document}

\input{chapter_01_test}

...............................

one two three four five

ein zwei drei vier fünf

ένα δύο τρία τέσσερα πέντε

\end{document}
```

and here is the external file *chapter_01_test.tex* :

```
 one two three four five

 ein zwei drei vier fünf

 ένα δύο τρία τέσσερα πέντε
```

this is the outcome:

[image]

So the question is why the imported file is unable to inherit the language settings as described on the main file?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't have the font so I can't test, but it sounds like an encoding issue. (Also because of the weird replacement characters) Which encoding does "chapter_01_test.tex" have?

Comment: Fontspec is for fonts not for language,  you need babel for language support.  But your problem is probably due to a wrong file encoding. Are you sure that the external file is utf8 encoded?

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer I am not sure. How can I tell?

Comment: your editor should normally show you somewhere the encoding. Or show in the log-file, xelatex should add warnings there, if the file is not utf8.

Comment: @user3060854 for Windows, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710374/get-encoding-of-a-file-in-windows. For Linux/Mac you can use `file chapter_01_test.tex` in a terminal, that should output `UTF-8 Unicode text`. If it doesn't, you need to re-save the file as UTF-8.